# find grained access control to a dynamodb table in a serverless setup with amozon cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-lambda

I have a set of users who authenticate via amazon cognito.

Now, using dynamodb, api gateway and lambda, I want to create a database where each entry:

- Has a creating (or owning) user
- Has a list of users that are allowed to edit

I want to create a setup where:

- Only the owner is allowed to delete the entry and change the list of users allowe to edit
- Only the users in the edit list are allowed to change the data in the entry

So how do I do this?
As far as I can see, I can not get the cognito username in aws lambda.

Is this possible using a api gateway proxy without any lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the Cognito user pool username to the Lambda function through API gateway. Broadly, the steps that you will need to follow will be.

```
1. SignUp and SignIn with Cognito user pools.
2. Use the access token to invoke a API gateway endpoint using [custom authorizes](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JK25U7Z9EUIU/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-User-Pools-with-API-Gateway).
3. Trigger the lambda function from API gateway and pass the user name in context.
```

Check this [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=726984) for more details.